# I am stuck with Java

Tags: java

1: Hi there. I don't know why my Java Cannot run. I think that my code is fine. Can anyone help me out?
This was the error message that was displayed after I run. The error message is displayed below.
It would be nice if someone can help me with this code. Thank you

This is the content of my file

```
A   1   50      3
B   2   1300    104
C   3   9000    900
D   4   1500
```

where

- A - D Represents the transaction code
- 1 - 4 represents the Employeenumber
- 50, 1300,9000,1500 represents the retail price

and the last section represents the commission that I have calculated

2. This is the Question.

A transaction record on a sales commission file contains the retail price of an item sold, a
transaction code which indicates the sales commission category to which an item can belong,
and the employee number of the person who sold the item. The transaction code can contain
the values A, B or C which indicate that the percentage commission will be 6%, 8% or 10%
respectively. Construct an algorithm that will read a record on the file, calculate the commission
owing for that record and print the retail price, commission and employee number.

Convert this to Java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;`

public class Question1
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (new File ("C:\\Users\\leeli\\Desktop\\Assignment2Qns1.txt"));
        double retailprice, commission;
        String Empnum;
        char transcode;

        while(input.hasNext())
    {
       retailprice = input.nextDouble();
       commission = input.nextDouble();``
       Empnum = input.next();
       transcode = input.next().charAt(0);

       if (transcode == 'A' || transcode == 'a')
       {
           commission = retailprice *0.06;
       }
       else if (transcode == 'B' || transcode == 'b')
        {
            commission = retailprice *0.08;
        }
       else if (transcode == 'C' || transcode == 'c')
       {
           commission = retailprice *0.1;
       }
       else 
       {
           commission = 0;
           System.out.print("Invalid transaction code");
       }
       System.out.println("Transaction code \t Employee Number \t Retail Price \t Commission");
       System.out.println(transcode + "\t" + Empnum +"\t" + retailprice +"\t" + commission);
}
}
}

//run:
//Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    //at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
    //at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    //at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2456)
    //at Question1.main(Question1.java:18)
//Java Result: 1
//BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately - this lets those with knowledge of the language you need help with to see your question.

Comment: There is a mismatch between your input file and the way that your code is trying to read it.  We can't give you much more help unless you show us a example input file *that cause the program to fail*.

Comment: could you also add the content of your file, the error you are getting is because input cannot be translated into valid double value.

Comment: Hello. The Content of the file is this

A 1 50          3
B 2 1300 104
C 3 9000 900
D 4 1500

Comment: I will edit it in the body. Sorry I am very new here guys. I appreciate for the help

Comment: @HimanshuSingh Hello.  I have edited my question.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Hi there. I am new here. What should I tag next time If i am asking  questions like this? I am using netbean as of now.

Comment: @StephenC Hello Stephen. I have already edited my question. Could you help me out? Im really keen to learn but sometimes just don't understand

Comment: You should tag with the language that you're asking about, and *only* the language you're asking about (which is Java, not Javascript)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Do you know how to handle this question?

Comment: No, because I know Javascript, and the question was tagged with Javascript, but the question is actually about Java, which is completely different

Comment: @CertainPerformance ah. Ok thanks alot anyway. I will tag as Java next time

Comment: I would suggest a title better than "I'm stuck with Java"

Answer (score 1):

Your order of reading from file matters a lot, you were getting the error because you were not reading the content in the correct order. You should read content in this order transcode, Empnum, retailprice, commission. This will fix your problem :

```
            transcode = input.next().charAt(0);
            Empnum = input.next();
            retailprice = input.nextDouble();
            commission = input.nextDouble();
```

Comment: run:
A 1 10.0 0.6
B 2 100.0 8.0
C 3 1000.0 100.0
Invalid transaction code
D 4 1500.0 0.0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: I did manage to run and my teacher told me to run with 3 test case by changing my input file and run again. I felt that this program is just to read the file and display. the If else statement doesnt work at all because I tried to remove the commission in the input file to blank and the program doesnt run and calculate the commission for me

Comment: i agree you'll get java.util.NoSuchElementException this error. So have to check that by putting condition that you have read something from file.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the input file and your code:

- In the input file, a record consists of a letter followed by two or three numbers.
- Your code is trying to read a record as two (floating point) numbers followed by two strings.
- So your code is trying to read a letter as if it was a number.  That won't work.  That is what is causing the `InputMismatchException` exception.

Solution: Change your code to match the input file's format.

---

If your sample input file is accurate, changing the order of the `nextXXX` calls is not sufficient.  That doesn't cope with the fact that the "commission" field is optional.  Instead, you should read each record using `Scanner::nextLine` then create a new `Scanner` to parse the record.

---

For future reference: you can solve these problems yourself by doing the following:

1. Read the stacktrace to find the exception that was thrown, where it was thrown, and what your code called to get to the place where the exception was thrown.
2. Read the javadocs for the exception and (typically) the API method that your code called.
3. Figure out what the exception means in the context of your program and its input.

Comment: I did manage to run and my teacher told me to run with 3 test case by changing my input file and run again. I felt that this program is just to read the file and display. the If else statement doesnt work at all because I tried to remove the commission in the input file to blank and the program doesnt run and calculate the commission for me

Comment: Your comment doesn't make sense to me.  Sorry.

Comment: Okay. I think I figured out. Thanks anyway @Stephen C